# How to display more than one contact in my contact page

Tags: react-native

Hi a just beginning a an internship and i have the following problem. I don't want to display only 1 contact but several contacts. I made this function to display retrieve and display the contacts. But I don't understand how I can display several contacts

```
        {this.state.display && (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.sms}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 25}}>{GLOBALS.CONTACT_NAME}</Text>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 25}}>{GLOBALS.CONTACT_NUMBER}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity> 
    )}
```

It shows this but I would like a list with all the contacts and not just one

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zxwt.jpg)

Comment: Presumably, you have an array of contacts somewhere. Look into using `.map` to turn each item of the array into a renderable component.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be:

```
{this.state.display && (
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.sms}>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 25}}>{GLOBALS.CONTACT_NAME1}</Text>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 25}}>{GLOBALS.CONTACT_NUMBER1}</Text>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 25}}>{GLOBALS.CONTACT_NAME2}</Text>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 25}}>{GLOBALS.CONTACT_NUMBER2}</Text>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 25}}>{GLOBALS.CONTACT_NAME3}</Text>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 25}}>{GLOBALS.CONTACT_NUMBER3}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity> 
)}
```

But this doesn't considered a nice practice, so I would suggest creating an array for your contacts like this:

```
const contacts = [
  { name: "name1", number: 1 },
  { name: "name2", number: 2 },
  { name: "name3", number: 3 },
  { name: "name4", number: 4 },
]
```

And then you can call the `.map` function of the array like this:

```
{this.state.display && 
  contacts.map(contact => (    
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.sms}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 25}}>{contact.name}</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 25}}>{contact.number}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

This iterates through the array, and returns the components for each element of the array.

Comment: What about using a flatlist instead? In case the contacts list gets too large.